# Why does this program run successfully but not the other?

Tags: c, sockets, server

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am trying to make a very simple server in C, the following code runs successfully, when I put 127.0.0.1:9001 it displays the content of the buffer in the page:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main()
{
    char buffer[255] = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n";
    int serverSocket, clientSocket;
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in serverAdress;
    serverAdress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAdress.sin_port = htons(9001);
    serverAdress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAdress, sizeof(serverAdress));
    listen(serverSocket, 2);
    clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL);
    send(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    return 0;
}
```

But in the following program, in which the only difference is error detection, when I run the following code it doesn't work, when I remove some of the error detections (for example in the accept function) it works perfectly again, when I remove error detection from bind function it sometimes works, but most times it will load the page for a second and disconnect, very weird. It's probably something very small, thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main()
{
    char buffer[255] = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n";
    int serverSocket, clientSocket;

    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(serverSocket<0)
    {
        printf("Socket creation failed\n");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serverAdress;

    serverAdress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAdress.sin_port = htons(9001);
    serverAdress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAdress, sizeof(serverAdress));

    //if(bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAdress, sizeof(serverAdress))!=0)
    //{
    // printf("Socket bind failure\n");
    //}
    if(listen(serverSocket, 2)!=0)
    {
        printf("Listen failed\n");
    }
    clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL);
    //if(clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL)==-1)
    //{
    //    printf("Accept connection failed\n");
    //}
    int result=0;
    if(result=send(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)==-1)
    {
        printf("Transmission send failed\n");
    }
    //printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With code like this you have no hope. Put in the proper error checking after *every* system call, and then review your findings. And when you get an error, *print the error,* with `perror()` or `strerror()`. Not some futile message of your own devising. Fix all this and probably you will answer your own question.

Comment: `result=send(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)==-1` hmm.... what do you expect this to do? My guess is that it isn't doing what you think....

Comment: The expression `result=send(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)==-1` is the same as `result = (send(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == -1)`- I.e. you assign the result of the comparison to `result`.

Comment: Or to put it differently... Is `a = b == c` the same as `(a = b) == c` or  the same as `a = (b == c)`

Answer (score 1):

I revised you code with additional error handling:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    char buffer[255] = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n";
    int serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(serverSocket == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in serverAdress;
    serverAdress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAdress.sin_port = htons(9001);
    serverAdress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if(bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAdress, sizeof(serverAdress)) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        return 1;
    }
    if(listen(serverSocket, 2) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        return 1;
    }
    int clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if(clientSocket == -1) {                                                                                
        perror("accept");  
        return 1;
    }
    int result = send(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    if(result == -1) {
        perror("send");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works on the first run.  If you run it again `bind()` will fail as the socket is in the TIME-WAIT state (client interaction not shown; I used `socat tcp-connect:localhost:9001 stdout` twice):

```
$ ./a.out; echo $?; ./a.out; echo $?; ss -a 'sport = :9001'
0            
bind: Address already in use
1
Netid                   State                       Recv-Q                   Send-Q                                     Local Address:Port                                      Peer Address:Port                    Process                   
tcp                     TIME-WAIT                   0                        0                                              127.0.0.1:9001                                         127.0.0.1:36024
```

You could either use a different port number, perhaps as an argument to your program, or allow program to reuse the address with:

```
    int serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    // ...
    if (setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){1}, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        return 1;
    }
```

Your `buffer` contains 52 bytes that are well defined `{[0] = 'A, ... [49] = 'A', [50] = '\n', [51] = '\0'}` but you send `sizeof(buffer) == 255` bytes to the client.  Usually, you keep track of the amount of data to send (often omitting the '\0' in favor of prefix length, or other means of framing).

Comment: `shutdown()` before `close()` is redundant except in certain specific circumstances. There is no 'good practice' about it.

Comment: @user207421 Removed as suggested.  This implies a RST instead of FIN, right?